# rosmake rosbuild_genmsg

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a small issue.

I just included in my src/file.cpp the lines

#include "sensor_msgs/PointCloud.h"
#include "hokuyo_listener_al/PointCloudWithOrigin.h" then I uncomment the line rosbuild_genmsg() in CMakeList.txt and I create the folder msg under my package directory.

Then I run rosmake  hokuyo_listener_al (which is my package name) and I get the following error:

fatal error: hokuyo_listener_al/PointCloudWithOrigin.h: No such file or directory

I have in my manifest.xml depend package="geometry_msgs", depend package="sensor_msgs"

Any suggestion?

In advance thank you :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62557/rosmake-rosbuild_genmsg/) by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 556 on 2013-05-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) on 2013-05-11**:
Is 'PointCloudWithOrigin.h' the result of your PointCloudWithOrigin.msg or a custom header file written by you ?

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2013-05-14**:
it is part of the prairiedog http://code.google.com/p/prairiedog/source/browse/?r=7 open source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, I found the mistake, I just forgot to add the file PointCloudWithOrigin.msg in the msg folder.

---

Originally posted by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) with karma: 556 on 2013-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0